# Server-side includes in ASP.NET (on Mono, Perhaps): Deprecated?

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, server-side-includes

I have a tiny job to perform on an HTML/ASPX site, and I don't have time to muck around with ASCX (though I've done it before quite a bit, and it is a wonderful technology). My question is: **are "classic" ASP server-side includes deprecated in ASP.NET, or merely not recommended?**

Will they work on Mono?

**Edit:** Yes I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894720/asp-net-equivalent-of-server-side-includes).

Comment: I'd strongly recommend against using them, even for a very small project. Familiarize yourself with the new way to do things, and it won't be any slower than using includes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server-side includes are unnecessary, and are usually turned off on production IIS sites. Don't use them.

Comment: Thanks for that. WHY are they turned off?

Comment: In addition to not being necessary, I seem to remember they were a security concern. I don't remember why - it's been 5 years since I've had to deal with them.