# How to include other page to aspx file

Tags: asp.net

i want to include other aspx file to main aspx file in asp.net i could do it in jsp the code in jsp include like that

```
<jsp:include page="footer.jsp" />
```

Comment: Hard to believe that something as basic as including text into an `aspx` template hasn't been implemented in a easy way. In Java there are four different one-liners to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14580120/whats-the-difference-between-including-files-with-jsp-include-directive-jsp-in

Comment: Sure just put this in a div on your page.  <!-- #Include virtual="/footer.aspx" -->

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not add another page to the existing page in asp.net.
Because `asp.net` does not allow two `form tag` in the same page.
There are feature like user control which you can use
More detail
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1739/User-controls-in-ASP-NET

### Edit 1

Further more
There is a concept of `Master page` and `content page`
Here is a good link for master page
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/325865/Creating-Master-Page-In-ASP-NET-2010

### Edit 2

Master page has a structure like below

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
   <title></title>
   <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
   </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div>
          <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

          </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
      </div>
   </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Few point to be noted

When you crate a Page you can add content only in `ContentPlaceHolder1`, there can be many of these.

You can put your `user-control` inside `master-page` also so that it will be reflected all over you pages.

### Edit 3

### Master pages

are actually user controls; you can verify this by going to the code-behind of your master page class, right-click on the class name and select "Go To Definition". You will see something like this:

```
public class MasterPage : UserControl
{
    ...
}
```

### User controls

are convenient for display components that are repeated withing a single project, such as menus and panels. The problem is that they do not generate .DLLs and have to be hand-copied to other projects, if needed.

Some good links

[ASP.NET equivalent of server side includes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894720/asp-net-equivalent-of-server-side-includes)
[How to include an external html file in asp.net page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938046/how-to-include-an-external-html-file-in-asp-net-page)

Answer (score 23):

This works for me. I can include my menu on any page I want:

```
<div ID="menuContent" runat="server">
    <!-- #Include virtual="/menu.aspx" -->
</div>
```

In my menu.aspx file I have raw html and some C# codeblocks and ASP will resolve those after inserting the content into the page. Great huh?

Comment: based on the OP question, this is the correct answer.  The other answers about MasterPages and whatnot do not directly answer the OP question.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.Net have [Master Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [User Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which help you do similar thing.

If you are using ASP.Net MVC, we have Partial View concept.

Answer (score 0):

Using #include will not work because it will introduce two page directives if the included file is an ASP.NET page. The OP will have to use Ajax to download the file and then place it in the page.

Comment: This doesn't really solve anything for the OP, or any later visitors. If this is the case you should provide some explanation of how to do so with Ajax