# ASP.NET equivalent of JSP include

Tags: c#, asp.net, jsp, webforms

In JSP I can share HTML code by using include:

```
<jsp:include page="subsection.jsp" >
```

For the life of me, I can't tell how in ASP.NET I should be including shared HTML. I could use a template control, but this really isn't the same thing. I could use a site master page and content placeholders, but this also is not the same and requires a different approach to developing my pages.

Am I out of luck or is there a function in ASP.NET similar to JSP's include?

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/862449.aspx/1

Comment: @JABFreeware and none of those links answered my question...

Comment: @adaam I didn't see any answer for my question there.

Comment: Sorry, here is a more appropriate link (I believe it answers your question): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15081386/how-to-include-other-page-to-aspx-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to enable it from the server then only you can use include html files.

```
<!-- #include file="Static/Menu.html" -->
```

Instructions to enable SSI in IIS7 are available at [http://tech.mikeal.com/](http://tech.mikeal.com/blog1.php/2008/08/05/server-side-includes-for-html-in-iis7)

For dynamic content, there is a built-in method of templating called MasterPages, this should be used instead.

Comment: thanks, this is the closest command I have seen to JSP include, even though it is happening in IIS.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are wanting can be accomplished in Asp.Net through [User Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e.aspx). If you were in Asp.Net MVC you would want to use [Partial Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410123%28v=vs.98%29.aspx).