# Use class library in vb net (webforms)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, razor, dll

I try to use class library in webform in vb (razor) (Using webmatrix)
The problem is every tutorial (that i found) is based on asp.net where u can drag drop buttons and double click. How can I add the class library in my webform.

(I am new to this)

Comment: Are you talking about a class library containing a WebForms user control? You can't use those in MVC.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894720/asp-net-equivalent-of-server-side-includes I am trying to use the class library like he is explaining @CodeCaster

Comment: I'm sorry but that makes little sense. Explain in your question very explicitly what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: I want to switch from classic asp to aspnet (i red that using class library is similar to classic asp) and use the code in <%%> with out refference ( and thats what i need)